# Ruby defaults to previous version

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've updated my version of ruby to 2.7.0. However, `ruby -v` reveals that the older version (2.3.7) is still the one that is running.

> ruby -v
>
> > ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
>
> whereis ruby
>
> > /usr/bin/ruby
>
> echo $PATH
>
> > /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/xxxxxxx/.rvm/bin
>
> ls /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems
>
> > 2.6.0 2.7.0

I can't understand why it is running the old version (in the path `/usr/bin/ruby`) when the `$PATH` variable has `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0` set first.

Note that I have restarted the terminal and the laptop. Same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RVM is your friend.

There may be some daemons on your machine that require a specific Ruby version or another script that runs and updates it. Many possibilities.

Generally though, changing system versions isn't the best idea.  Whenever you can, use a version manager. It'll save you loads of headache and keep things nicely sandboxed on your machine :)

https://rvm.io/

Comment: Yeah, that's a journey in itself. Requires gpg keys, etc. But that's the route I went and not it works. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what SethGoodluck suggested, rbenv is another version manager. You can set different ruby version for each different project.

You can check it out here: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv